# How do i install a Prject interpeter that cannot be found in the pycharm explorer

Tags: python, pycharm

I am trying to install the huobi_python lib to my pycharm however i'm unable to do so. I have tried multiple times to add it and google it but did not succseed. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Github link:https://github.com/huobiapi/huobi_Python

Running windows 10, no i cannot find it in Project interpeter and with the + sign. Those are mostly REST api's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't add it as an interpreter.

Since the project isn't available as pip install, you'd have to build it from source. Meaning clone the repo, and run the command listed in the installation section from the command prompt. Also make sure that you're using Python3.7, as listed there.

Your interpreter then would have to just be Python 3.7, which will allow you to import the modules from other Python code

```
from huobi import RequestClient

# your code
```

Comment: So i installed it with pip setup.py install but then i can't really follow. Do i need to move the import the huobi map inside of my code? Sorry if this is again a stupid question but i really need help if you want i can send some btc over later

Comment: `python3 setup.py install`... The page didn't mention pip. But yes, you'd write something like `from huobi import RequestClient`